# Using git clone in existing application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have existing app.

I did like this:

```
git clone https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize.git -b master
```

To use ActiveAdmin-globalize gem. After this I have new folder **activeadmin-globalize**, but how can I actually use this gem, because in these subfolders are other folders like app/ lib/ config/ etc.

How can I make it to work, but still keep my existing app functionality ?
Thanks

Comment: to use it u dont need to clone it, just add 
gem "activeadmin-globalize", github: 'stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize',
branch: 'master' in your gemfile and do bundle

Comment: @Rahul Singh Then it gives me error fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if u still got same error try with regular git syntax

```
gem "activeadmin-globalize", git: 'https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize', branch: 'master'
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it gives me this error. Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel"

Comment: clear your gemfile.lock and then again do bundle install

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to Gemfile

```
gem "activeadmin-globalize", github: 'stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize',
branch: 'master'
```

and in root dir run:

```
bundle install
```

---

Read please https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize#installation

Comment: Then it gives me error fatal: unable to connect to github.com: github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out